# Convert unsigned int to int and long in C++

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void fun1(int off) {
  cout << "fun1 " << off << endl;
}

void fun2(long off) {
  cout << "fun2 " << off << endl;
}

int main() {
  unsigned int a;
  a = 50;
  fun1(-a);
  fun2(-a);

  return 0;
}
```

The output of this program:

```
fun1 -50
fun2 4294967246
```

If I change `unsigned int a` --> `unsigned long a`, the output are both -50.

Is this behavior well defined? What's the related rules?

Note: I use 64 bit Linux, so int is 4 bytes, long is 8 bytes. Compiler is gcc 12.

Comment: `uint` is not a standard type, you need to look up how it is defined. Presumably it is `unsigned int` - which seems to be smaller than `unsigned long` on your system (which isn't guaranteed to be the case)

Comment: @UnholySheep `uint` is `unsiged int`, I have edited the problem to make it more clear.

Comment: The output of `fun2` is well defined (assuming the given sizes). The output of `fun1` used not be well defined because you are overflowing the `int` parameter. I have a feeling this might have changed in a recent C++ version? The rule always used to be that overflows in unsigned types are well defined but overflows in signed types are not. But as I say I have a feeling this has changed.

Comment: According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions) this changes in C++20, although the language is a bit hard to follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the results are implementation-defined, because the size of types is implementation-defined, amongst other things.

On your system I am assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`, `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(long) == 8`. Within these assumptions:

- The value of `-a` is always `4294967246` of type `unsigned int` .
- The case `fun2` is well-defined as `4294967246` is in the range of `long`.
- The case `fun1` is different because `4294967246` is out of range for `int`:

  - since C++20, well-defined to `-50`
  - before C++20, implementation-defined.